# Inno Setup Sqlite3 plugin

Tags: plugins, sqlite, setup-deployment

How to work with Sqlite3 database in inno setup. Which dll files and interface functions should be used. Need to perform read, write and traverse operations.

Answer (score 2):

You could include the `sqlite3.exe` tool into the setup, and call it to execute your commands:

```perl
[Run]
Filename: "{tmp}\sqlite3.exe"; Parameters: """{userappdata}\MyProg\MyData.db"" ""INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(1,2,3)"""; Flags: runhidden
```

Using SQLite's C API directly from InnoSetup would be rather complex.
The easiest way would be to write your own .exe or .dll and call it from the setup.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can you recommend me any dll file to for quick use.

Comment: There is none; you have to write your own.

Comment: This worked perfectly, I just had to put the path of the file in quotation marks because there were spaces. +1 `"""{userappdata}\MyProg\MyData.db"" ""INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(1,2,3)"""`

Comment: @CL.-- you don't have to write your own. There are precompiled libraries and executables located here: https://sqlite.org/download.html

Comment: @Andy And how would you use it directly from InnoSetup? The C API is not suited for quited use.

Comment: There is an `sqlite3.exe` file in the `sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3270100.zip` package. You can also import DLLs (http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptdll) if you don't want to use a CLI.

Comment: I may have mis-read the question. Sorry about that. I thought he was asking for sqlite.exe, not a DLL.